# Xcode 5.1 doesn't load on OS X 10.9.2 and 10.9.3

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-mavericks

I have a situation whereby a fresh installation of Xcode 5.1 fails to load properly at all either on OS X Mavericks 10.9.2 and 10.9.3.

I had removed , at the command line , my previous installation of Xcode 4.x as it no longer loaded on Mavericks and the Command Line Tools associated with that older installation of Xcode.

The CLI instructions used where

```
sudo rm -r /Library/Developer/Xcode;
sudo rm -r /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools;
sudo rm -r /Library/Developer/Frameworks;
```

I have installed the latest Command Line Tools and the latest Xcode 5.1 application using the dmg files available within the Developer downloads on Apple's Developer site.

On trying to start the Xcode IDE I get a rudimentary menu as seen in the image attached.

[image: Rudimentary menu for Xcode that shows on startup of Xcode]

If I try to switch to spaces I find a strip of Xcode project icons at the bottom of the screen.

[image: Xcode project icon strip]

Clicking on any of these icons does not raise the project associated with that project icon, even though that asset is available on the HDD.

Sometimes the Xcode application subsequently closes, despite not having been instructed to close. Sometimes it remains open, albeit it in a state where it is not at all usable as per its design.

The only messages that I receive in the Console are:-

```
18/03/2014 10:12:29.051 Xcode[8698]:  DeveloperPortal: Using pre-existing current store at URL (file:///Users/cybero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeveloperPortal%205.1.db).
18/03/2014 12:15:44.172 Xcode[8698]: GetDYLDEntryPointWithImage(/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/Current/AppKit,_NSCreateAppKitServicesMenu) failed.
```

Comment: Try it from the guest account; if it works there your other account's Xcode preferences may be wacked.

Comment: That proved right. I finally got around to trying that out

Comment: Should I therefore delrte those preferences!

Answer (score 0):

i am developing quartz composer plugins now and came up with exactly the same behaviour of Xcode 6.1 on OSX 10.9.5. Tryed to solve that
Error Message and Xcode not loading issue.

```
GetDYLDEntryPointWithImage(/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/Current/AppKit,_NSCreateAppKitServicesMenu) failed.
```

So the tip of geowar pointed me in the right direction. In a different User Profile Xcode started just like expected. So not Xcode was broken, just the presets are.
Methods who didnt solve the problem:

1. Reinstalling Xcode from the Appstore did'nt work.
2. Manually reset via `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode` didnt work.
3. Starting Xcode as rootuser via `sudo open --new /Applications/Xcode.app` didnt work.
4. Manually moving my own Frameworks out of its Folders so they wont load didnt work.
5. Starting Quartz Composer and changing Preferences **did work to solve it!**

Here the way to do who solved it to me.

```
a) open Quartz Composer App
b) open Preferences...
c) click on "Viewer" while holding down "Alt"-Key
d) Three new hidden Preference Tabs will show up.
e) in (System) Tab go down the list and turn off 
    "QCEditCompositions"
    "GFLogErrors"
    "GFLogWarnings"
    "GFLogWindow"
f) quit Quartz Composer App
g) open Quartz Composer App to proof if changes where made (You should not see the "loaded Compositions list" anymore. 
h) quit Quartz Composer again.
i) start Xcode should work.
```

let me know if that worked, i will fill a bug report at apple developer forum.

Comment: I have shared your answer on the Facebook QC group, but as my installation base is different from what it was at the time of posting the original question I am unable to prove its usefulness to what had been my situation. Thanks for the input though.